# Consecutive goals scored by one player for a team

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, nhl

What is the NHL record for most consecutive goals scored by one player for a team? Jason Zucker of the Minnesota Wild has just scored 6 straight for them, over 3 games.

Answer (score 2):

This is the longest streak of consecutive goals by one player in Wild history, and Zucker is the first player to score six consecutive team goals since Glen Murray did it for the Boston Bruins from Jan. 29 - Feb. 1, 2004, according to the Elias Sports Bureau.

However ***the longest run in NHL history is seven goals***, set by *Cy Denney* of the Ottawa Senators from Feb. 28 - March 7, 1921 and matched by *Brian Noonan* with the Chicago Blackahawks from Dec. 27-29, 1991.

***[Source: www.nhl.com](https://www.nhl.com/news/nhl-morning-report-news-notes-nov-12/c-292910698)***